# Moss Covered Chests, do they respawn?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I know I am late to the "Pandarian Gate." However, I finally made it to the Timeless Isle and discovered moss covered chests. These things are awesome for a casual gamer like me. Since I started looting them though, I can't find a definitive "they do" or "they do not" respawn. Can anyone shed light into this? I've seen all answers from "yes" and "no" to "here are a few that do respawn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are single use items and are limited to level 90 characters. Also on the island you can find Sturdy Chest, Skull-Covered Chest, Smouldering Chest, and Blazing Chest. These are all single use chests.

There are also chests that reset weekly. Near the bottom of this [Wowpedia](http://wowpedia.org/Moss-Covered_Chest) page, you can find a list these chests.

That being said, the best source I can find for this is this [comment on WoWHead](http://www.wowhead.com/object=221670#comments:id=1897546:reply=693902). I would consider it a reliable source, as Perculia is the Site Director for WoWHead.

Comment: [This is the best guide I've seen on the subject.](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1328815-In-depth-Timeless-Isle-Hidden-Chest-Guide!)

Comment: Great guide. I knew I should have checked mmo-champ for a guide. Been out of the game a long time.